# Python strptime() format code '%H' for number of hours greater than 23?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I must add a given number of hours:minutes to a date, once I try to format the method string parameter to datetime I am getting the below error:

```
 myTime = '236:22'
 myTime_str = '%H:%M'
 myTime_time = datetime.strptime(myTime, myTime_str )

ValueError: time data '236:22' does not match format '%H:%M'
```

As I couldn't find a [strptime() format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) that allows the hour (236) to be greater than 23 I am wondering if is there other function or library, rather than datetime, that would help me to before addressing it "in the method"

Comment: first create a datetime object with which hours and min to which u need to add hours/min and then add the hours/min to that datetime object.

Comment: A datetime cannot have hours greater than 23. Is your “timestamp” actually a *duration*, for which you should use a `timedelta`‽

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the requirement as follows:

```
duration_hours = int(duration.split(':')[0])
duration_minutes = int(duration.split(':')[1])
new_time = given_time + timedelta(hours=duration_hours,minutes=duration_minutes)'
```

Comment: You shouldn't `.split()` twice, though ;)